# Find string in array of regex

Tags: php, regex, search

what is the best way to check string in array of regex patterns?
Is something like preg_grep?

I need result like this:

```
$string = 'myFooString';

$patterns = [
  'some(regex|foo)',
  'my.+String',
  'anotherRegex'
];

$isMatchWithAny = false;

foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
    if (preg_match('/' . $pattern . '/', $string)){
        $isMatchWithAny = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: so do you faced any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `preg_grep` provides the opposite of what you're asking, a single pattern but an array of inputs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

In this case, your example code provides the simplest result of what you say you are trying to achieve:

```
$string = 'myFooString';

$patterns = [
  'some(regex|foo)',
  'my.+String',
  'anotherRegex'
];

$isMatchWithAny = false;

foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
    if (preg_match('/' . $pattern . '/', $string)){
        $isMatchWithAny = true;
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($isMatchWithAny);
```

https://eval.in/858431

The only other way would be if you wrote a more complex pattern to encompass all the different patterns you're searching for but that would be dependent on your application and use case.

Comment: My mistake. When I wrote "Is something like preg_grep?" I mean function like preg_grep but for my problem - which is free of loop over array (I know it do it internally).

Comment: Unfortunately none of the `preg_` functions would solve your problem: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php